# How to convert a Public Key to a base64 Public Key?

Tags: curl, base64, public-key-encryption

Im trying to write a script, which is sending data to a sftp server via public key auth.
Im using cURL for that.

After some try and error I got an valid connection, but with the following output:

```
* SSH authentication methods available: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
* Using ssh public key file pub.key
* Using ssh private key file private.ppk
* SSH public key authentication failed: Invalid key data, not base64 encoded
* Agent based authentication successful
* Authentication complete
```

It worked on my laptop so i just tried to make the script running to my colleague, but on her laptop the connections fails.

After that I realized the line *SSH public key authentication failed: Invalid key data, not base64 encode*.

I neither know why a "Agent based authentication" is successful on my side (or what this really means)  nor why its not working on my colleagues laptop.

I also didn't found a way to convert my public-key into a base64 public-key.

Kind Regards
Animal21

EDIT:
OK after searching the web and trying things out I have decided to check if my keys are valid base64 string, so I wrote a function is C# and surprise surprise my keys ARE base64 encoded...

What does this tells my now?

Kind Regards

Comment: I know this is way late, but my best guess here is that whatever environment your key was in did not allow for line breaks or whitespace in the key text. As for the agent authentication on your machine, it's probably the SSH-AGENT which is a daemon that tracks your SSH keys and known hosts. The agent knows the right key and trust to connect so agent authentication works, but it's telling you that the key you provided fails to authenticate (public key authentication failed). This means the key you're providing is not the exact same key that your agent knows to use.

Comment: Here's how to convert to base64 on the command line btw:
LINUX -- base64 -w 0 < my_ssh_key,  OS X -- base64 < my_ssh_key

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Try this:
http://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html

Online way to Encodes or decodes a string so that it conforms to the Base64 Data Encodings specification (RFC 4648).